# Can i make a trespass div area like this?

Tags: html, css

[image]

I'm new to front end design.

made a code like this.

```
<div id="header">
header
</div>
<div id="content">
content
</div>

<div id="sidebar">
in here will be login module
</div>
```

how can the sidebar will be trespassing area like the pic?

any good solution?

Comment: I'm confused: What is the "trespassing area"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course it's possible. Anything is possible with CSS ;)

You have to learn to use the `position` property and `float`.

[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/64Uq5/2/)

```
#wrap{
width:100%;
margin:0 auto;
}
#header{
width:100%;
height:50px;
background:orange;
}
#content{
width:100%;
height:500px;
background:green;
float:;
}
#sidebar{
width:25%;
height:550px;
background:red;
float:left;
position:relative;
bottom:550px;
left:20px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you simple need to position sidebar like this, you can use `position: absolute`. As a very basic test add following classes to your HTML:

```
body {
   margin:0
}

div {
    border: 1px solid black
}

#header {
    height: 50px;
}

#content {
    height:200px
}

#sidebar {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 250px;       
}
```

And here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Mxqh4/

Again this is just a demo, and in a real project would have to be dynamically adjusted, but that's should give you a start.